# What is "to cram pearls onto a handful of pages" when making an application to a College?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> You can't believe that after 12 years of education **your future
>   depends on what pearls of genius you can cram onto a handful of
>   pages** – or that complete strangers will sit in a room and determine
>   if you will be "worthy" of attending their institution.

*Making the Most of Your College Applications By Melissa Algranati and Jennifer Gioia*

How should I understand the phrase in bold?

Comment: You should really state more narrowly what you do not understand, and tell us what steps you've taken so far to try to figure out the meaning. Do you not understand why "pages" are being referred to? Or is it that **pearls of genius** is opaque to you?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand the meaning of the key words:

- **pearl** - a thing of great worth
- **genius** - a very high level of skill or ability
- **to cram** - to put things into a space that is too small

So, here's how we can paraphrase the sentence:

> You can't believe that after 12 years of education your future depends
>   on **a few pages *(of your college admission essay)* on which you should write something truly extraordinary**, or
>   that complete strangers will sit in a room and determine if you will
>   be "worthy" of attending their institution.